# Enforcing "zero-or-one to one" relationship on SQL database?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

I have a `Post` entity and a `FbPost` entity.

`Post.FbPost` is either null or a `FbPost`, and no two `Post` entities can reference the same `FbPost` entity. In other words, `zero-or-one to one`.

What is the proper way to enforce this as `zero-or-one to one` instead of `many to one` in SQL Server (ideally)?

If that's not possible, how can I enforce this on EF level?

Comment: I think this answer is good for you too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6455626/ef4-1-possible-to-have-zero-or-one-to-zero-or-one-0-1-to-0-1-relationship/6456037#6456037

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Normally, you would probably attempt to have the foreign key (in the source table) be nullable and place a unique constraint on it.

The fact that it's nullable means that you can have an null entry in the source table that does not refer to an entry in the target table. And, if it's not null, the unique constraint ensures that only one row of the source table can reference a row in the target table.

Unfortunately, at least with SQL Server <sup>(a)</sup>, NULLs in uniquely constrained columns have to be unique as well, although this "breaks" the SQL guideline that NULL is not equal to any value, including another NULL. So basically, this method won't work with SQL Server.

One possible way out of this quandary <sup>(b)</sup> is a foreign key constraint with a nullable column, but *no* unique constraint. This will allow you to ensure you either don't reference a row in the target table at all (NULL in the source table) or reference a target row (any non-NULL value in the source table).

It doesn't, however, give you your "only one source row can reference the target row" requirement. That could be added with an before-(insert/update) trigger which would check every other row in the source table to ensure no other row already references the target row.

And you should almost *always* prefer constraints in the database itself. You never know when a rogue application (malignant or buggy) will connect to your database and decide not to follow the rules.

---

<sup>(a)</sup> The following text, paraphrased from [here](http://troels.arvin.dk/db/rdbms/#constraints-unique), shows the differing support for nullable unique columns in several DBMS products:

**The standard:**

As the constraint name indicates, a (set of) column(s) with a UNIQUE constraint may only contain unique (combinations of) values.

A column, or a set of columns, which is subject to a UNIQUE constraint must also be subject to a NOT NULL constraint, unless the DBMS implements an optional "NULLs allowed" feature (feature ID 591). The optional feature adds some additional characteristics to the UNIQUE constraint:

First, columns involved in a UNIQUE constraint may also have NOT NULL constraints, but they do not have to. Secondly, if columns with UNIQUE constraints do not also have NOT NULL constraints, then the columns may contain any number of NULL 'values' (a logical consequence of the fact that NULL is not equal to NULL).

**PostgreSQL:**

Follows the standard, including the optional NULLs allowed feature.

**DB2:**

Follows the non-optional parts of the UNIQUE-constraint. Doesn't implement the optional NULLs allowed feature.

**MSSQL:**

Follows the standard with a twist.

MSSQL offers the NULLs allowed feature, but allows at most one instance of a NULL 'value', if NULLs are allowed. In other words, it breaks characteristic 2 in the above description of the standard.

**MySQL:**

Follows the standard, including the optional NULLs allowed feature.

**Oracle:**

Follows the standard with a twist regarding multi-column UNIQUE-constraints.

The optional NULLs allowed feature is implemented: If the UNIQUE-constraint is imposed on a single column, then the column may contain any number of NULLs (as expected from characteristic 2 in the above description of the standard). However, if the UNIQUE-constraint is specified for multiple columns, then Oracle sees the constraint as violated if any two rows

- contain at least one NULL in a column affected by the constraint
- identical, non-NULL values in the rest of the columns affected by the constraint

---

<sup>(b)</sup> The other way out, of course, is to choose a DBMS that implements this feature, like PostgreSQL or MySQL.

That may not be possible in your specific case but it should be at least *contemplated.* For example, I steer clear of Oracle because of its inability to discern NULLs from empty strings in certain character columns, though others aren't probably as "purist" (my wife would say "anal retentive") as I am :-)

Comment: I too posted this answer, but after reading the docs... "*Also, unlike PRIMARY KEY constraints, UNIQUE constraints allow for the value NULL. However, as with any value participating in a UNIQUE constraint, **only one null value is allowed per column***" I'm a little confused. I'm sure I've done exactly this, but the docs seem to think I wouldn't be able to.

Comment: @spender, you're right. SQLServer doesn't _quite_ follow the standard with respect to this feature. I've updated the answer to correct that, and provided a possible way out of it.

Comment: Please see my answer for (what I believe to be) the best solution, which involves no index or special constraint at all beyond a simple FK.

Answer (score 5):

Create a unique filtered index:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX Post_Unq_FbPost ON dbo.Post(FbPost) WHERE FbPost IS NOT NULL;
```

Also create a foreign key, of course.

Comment: This is the most simple solution, but it does require SQL Server 2008 or above to use a filtered index.

Comment: It isn't the most simple solution. Please see my answer which doesn't require an extra index.

Comment: @ErikE a one-liner is more complex than a thirty-line solution? I am not so sure...

Comment: If you measure complexity of the solution by lines of code required to achieve that state, then maybe. But if you measure complexity by the final state--the finished product itself, then my solution is simpler.

Answer (score 2):

**Superclass It!**

I think the best solution is to make the `Post` table a *superclass* of the `FBPost` table. (Note: I'm going to use `PostID` and `FBPostID` here to make it absolutely clear what I'm referring to.) That is, remove the `FBPostID` column from your `Post` table entirely, after updating the `FBPost.FBPostID` column to match the corresponding `PostID`. Instead of each `FBPostID` having its own unique value, it will share the same value as the `PostID`. In my professional opinion, this is the *right* way to model a one-to-zero-or-one relationship. It has a huge advantage of being foolproof, and not requiring any additional indexes, triggers, or constraints beyond what a simple FK already provides.

Note: I'm assuming that we can just update the `FBPostID` column in `FBPost` once we drop the (presumed) PK on it. If it is an `identity` column, then more work will be required--just to add a new column that will become the new PK, and to rename the original column. If column order matters, the data will have to be moved to a new table in order to make a new column appear in the desired location.

Be sure to think about concurrency while working on this so no data can be improperly read or modified while the change is taking place or before the altered data handling is updated.

**Why you would choose this**

When you're modeling an `is-a` relationship instead of a `has-a` relationship, and the two entities participate as zero-to-zero-or-one, then they should share the same surrogate key, because really they're the same entity (you're actually modeling an `is-sometimes-a` relationship).

Even though changing to this database model will take a bit of work, it's totally worth it to repair a suboptimal design. Your relational database's design should always leverage the core relational functionality available. Why would you do anything else:

- You would never write a trigger to enforce a foreign key relationship, since databases offer explicit foreign key constraints that do the job with 100% reliability.
- You would never modify the system tables directly to create a new table, you'd issue a `CREATE TABLE` command.
- And so on and so forth.

Similarly, you would use a foreign key/primary key combination to model an `is-sometimes-a` relationship, without having to do weird NULL-allowing unique constraints or filtered indexes to accomplish that purpose.

**Example Change Script**

It's not even too bad! Here is some script that should get you pretty well started:

```sql
BEGIN TRAN;
ALTER TABLE dbo.Post DROP CONSTRAINT FK_Post_FBPostID; -- referencing FBPost
-- Also remove all FKs from any other tables referencing FBPostID

ALTER TABLE dbo.FBPost DROP CONSTRAINT PK_FBPost; -- FBPostID column not PK
ALTER TABLE dbo.FBPost ADD OriginalFBPostID int;
UPDATE dbo.FBPost WITH (HOLDLOCK, UPDLOCK) SET OriginalFBPostID = FBPostID;

UPDATE F
SET F.FBPostID = P.PostID
FROM
   dbo.FBPost F
   INNER JOIN dbo.Post P
      ON F.OriginalFBPostID = P.FBPostID;

-- Perform a similar update on all other tables referencing FBPostID

-- Now, the two most important changes
ALTER TABLE dbo.FBPost ADD CONSTRAINT PK_FBPost PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (FBPostID);
ALTER TABLE dbo.FBPost ADD CONSTRAINT FK_FBPost_PostID FOREIGN KEY
   REFERENCES dbo.Post (PostID); -- This is where the magic happens!

ALTER TABLE dbo.SomeTable ADD CONSTRAINT FK_SomeTable_FBPostID FOREIGN KEY
   REFERENCES dbo.FBPost (FBPostID); -- and all other tables referencing FBPostID

EXEC sp_rename 'dbo.Post.FBPostID', 'OriginalFBPostID'; -- should stop using it
ALTER TABLE dbo.Post DROP COLUMN FBPostID; -- Or even better, remove it.
COMMIT TRAN;
ALTER TABLE dbo.FBPost DROP COLUMN OriginalFBPostID; -- Meaningless now
-- If you keep OriginalFBPostID and it is identity, please copy the values
-- to a new non-identity column and drop it so you don't keep generating more
```

Finally, modify your `Post`/`FBPost` insertion code to use the `PostID` as the `FBPostID`.

**New Query Appearance**

Just to drive home the point, your joins between the tables used to look like this:

```sql
SELECT
   P.Something,
   F.SomethingElse
FROM
   dbo.Post P
   INNER JOIN dbo.FBPost F
      ON P.FBPostID = F.FBPostID
```

But now they will look like this:

```sql
SELECT
   P.Something,
   F.SomethingElse
FROM
   dbo.Post P
   INNER JOIN dbo.FBPost F
      ON P.PostID = F.FBPostID -- the important part
```

The problem is completely solved now! Your tables even take up less space (losing the `FBPostID` column from `Post`). You don't have to monkey around with an FK that allows multiple NULLs. With a PK on `FBPostID` in the `FBPost` table it is obvious that you can only have one `FBPost` row per `FBPostID`.

Answer (score 0):

NULL able gives you the 0...
a UNIQUE CONSTRAINT on your FK reference will give you the 1.

Comment: The unique constraint would mean that only a single null value is allowed in the FK column. I think. The docs... "*Also, unlike PRIMARY KEY constraints, UNIQUE constraints allow for the value NULL. However, as with any value participating in a UNIQUE constraint, **only one null value is allowed per column***"

Comment: Yes my bad. SQL Server & Oracle are different in this regard. In SQL Server 2008 you can create a conditional unique index: 

`create unique index z on LiS(a) where a is not null;` 

Not as good as a constraint (in my opinion) but it should get you there.