# one to zero or one relationship ASP.NET MVC

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, relationship

I have a ASP.NET MVC 4 application with EF and I'm not using CodeFirst.
I want my SQL tables to look like this :

Orders 1 ---- 0...1 OrdersWithShipment

```
CREATE TABLE Orders (
OrderId int NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
OrderDate date NOT NULL,
OrderNo int NOT NULL,
ShipmentId Int NULL
CONSTRAINT [Orders_PK] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
   [OrderId] ASC
))

CREATE TABLE OrdersWithShipment (
ShipmentId int NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
OrderId int NULL,
ShipmentDate date NOT NULL 
CONSTRAINT [OrdersWithShipment_PK] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[ShipmentId] ASC
))
```

**Q** : What do I need to do (in SQL and EF) so that I have a 1 --- 0...1 relationship ?

Edit : 
Can I use unique filtered index [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8116409/enforcing-zero-or-one-to-one-relationship-on-sql-database)

Comment: This has nothing to do with ASP.NET MVC. You should rather edit your subject and tags to make it more expressive in respect to your problem and technologies.

Comment: You are right, only a lot of folks interested in ASP.NET MVC may encounter this problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how an `1..0-1` could be defined in SQL (`ShipmentId` removed from both tables):

```
CREATE TABLE Orders (
OrderId int NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
OrderDate date NOT NULL,
OrderNo int NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [Orders_PK] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
  ( [OrderId] ASC )
) ;

CREATE TABLE OrdersWithShipment (
OrderId int NOT NULL,
ShipmentDate date NOT NULL, 
CONSTRAINT [OrdersWithShipment_PK] 
  PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
  ( [OrderId] ASC ),
CONSTRAINT [Orders_OrdersWithShipment_FK] 
  FOREIGN KEY 
    ( [OrderId] )
  REFERENCES [Orders] 
    ( [OrderId] )
) ;
```

Comment: Thank you for giving correct advice where so many are advocating NULLable FKs from the `Orders` table side.

Comment: @ErikE thnx. I'm not sure though how/if EF can handle non-identity primary keys. Some frameworks require surrogate keys in every table.

Answer (score 2):

EF doesn't support unique keys (except primary keys), so you will not achieve one-to-one relation with this setup. If you want one-to-one relation you have to remove `OrderId` column from `OrderWithShipment` table and `ShipmentId` from `Orders` table and put your foreign key constraint directly on `ShipmentId` in `OrdersWithShipment` table. That will build one-to-one relation for EF where `Orders` is principal table for relation with `OrdersWithShipment`.

Comment: This answer is good, but very confusing because it doesn't explain clearly that by recommending to remove `OrderId`, you mean that `ShipmentID` will no longer be `identity` and will take the logical place of `OrderID`. In my opinion, since there is no other subtype table also needing its own distinguishing name (from Order) then it is best to keep it as `OrderID`.