# Special one-one db relationship

Tags: database-design, relational-database

It might be a stupid question, but i'm new in databases' stuffs so excuse me.
Is this relationship valid:
x entity 1..1 -> 1..1 y entity,
 it's 1-1 after all, the same can be said for this one too:
0..1 -> 1
but there's still a slight difference though.

Answer (score 0):

x 1..1 -> 1..1 y : Each row in x is linked to one and only one row in y.

x 0..1 -> 1 y : Some rows in x are linked to one and only one row in y.

In the first scenario, x as to be linked to a row in y, with a foreign key for example.

Example : You have an EmployeeID. Each employee as an ID and each ID is linked to an employee.

In the second scenario, x doesn't have to be link, but if he is, it's linked to only one row in y.

Exemple : You can have a cellphone number. If you have one, you have only one and each cellphone number is linked to only one person.

For more details : [Cardinality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinality_(data_modeling))

Comment: thanks for replying, i was confused about it because if i set it in this way in sql server when i connect my c# app to database if i created an object of eg. entity x an error occurs as i'm supposed to create an object of type y firstly, the same thing will occur if i did the opposite direction. That's why i thought it's not possible although logically it's.

Comment: @HaythamTahboub You'll need to have your foreign key accept null values. This link will probably be helpful! [Enforcing Zero or one to one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8116409/enforcing-zero-or-one-to-one-relationship-on-sql-database)