# How to configure zero or one to zero or one relationship with bi-directional navigation with FluentAPI

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I'm trying to create a 0..1 to 0..1 relation in entity framework's fluent API. The objective would be to configure the relation navigable from both ends.

The ideia is: One user might be a physician and a physician may or may not have an associated user.

It would be useful to have a bi-directional relation for navigation purposes.

Also, the foreignKey side, on Pysician, should have the ForeignKey property exposed (to set a User ID).

Here's my model and fluentAPI configuration

```
public class Physician
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string ProfessionalName { get; set; }

    public long? PhysicianUserID { get; set; }
    public virtual User PhysicianUser { get; set; }
}

public class User 
{

    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }

    public virtual Physician UserPhysician { get; set; }
}

        modelBuilder.Entity<Physician>()
            .HasOptional(A => A.PhysicianUser)
            .WithOptionalDependent(A => A.UserPhysician);

        modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
            .HasOptional(A => A.UserPhysician)
            .WithOptionalPrincipal(A => A.PhysicianUser);
```

The problem is that EF creates a property on Physician called PhysicianUser_ID (instead of using the one I provided). I've tried to add a [ForeignKey()] declaration on the physician entity but that resulted in validations errors.

How can I configure this type of relation ? (If indeed possible)

Comment: can a Physician be associated with more than one user?

Comment: No, just one (or zero)

Comment: Your requirement seems to be `one-or-zero` to `one-or-zero` relationship which I think is impossible even in sql, [similar post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6455626/ef4-1-possible-to-have-zero-or-one-to-zero-or-one-0-1-to-0-1-relationship), you either needs to implement it as [one to one-or-zero](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591620.aspx#RequiredToOptional) OR [one to one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591620.aspx#RequiredToRequired), OR might even [many to many](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591620.aspx#ManyToMany)

Comment: You are correct Mr Chandra. This constraint cannot be implemented in SQL. If you want, make an answer out of your comment and I will accept it.

Comment: it's okay, you can share the workaround of your problem and mark it as answer

Answer (score -1):

You need to tell Ef how to map the key

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
        .HasOptional(A => A.UserPhysician)
        .WithOptionalPrincipal(A => A.PhysicianUser)
        .Map(A => A.MapKey("PhysicianUserID"));
```

Comment: have you tried this code and see what happens? "Column names in each table must be unique. Column name 'PhysicianUserID ' in table 'Physicians' is specified more than once." .. SqlException

Comment: yup - deserving of downvote, forgot op wanted to expose the PhysicianUserID